# Newtonsoft issue with IDynamicMetaObjectProvider implementing classes on deserialization

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, json.net

currently I stumble upon a issue with Newtonsofts Json library, which is a total mystery to me.

I'm having a few classes, which are implementing the IDynamicMetaObjectProvider interface. Serialising several objects to json is no issue, I get exactly the json I expect from every instance of the object.

However deserialisation is giving me a headache. From what I have observed so far it seems like that the library is caching the value for every dynamic property it can't find and keeps this while the application is running. So as example I'm having following three Jsons:

```
{ "PropA": "1" }
{ "PropA": "2", "PropB": "1" }
{ "PropA": "3", "PropB": "2", "PropC": "1" }
```

Deserialising this the Jsons in a row will give me following .NET objects:

```
{ "PropA": "1" }
{ "PropA": "1", "PropB": "1" }
{ "PropA": "1", "PropB": "1", "PropC": "1" }
```

HOWEVER! If I change the target type from the one implementing IDynamicMetaObjectProvider to Dicitionary or simply dynamic, the deserialised object will have the properties set correctly.

My class is having an index property, setting a breakpoint on the setter, that already the setter is provided with the wrong value (so it is no issue with the implementation of my class).

```
public abstract class DynamicModelObject : IDynamicMetaObjectProvider //, IPropertyIndexer //, IDictionary<String, Object>
    {
        [NotMapped]
        [JsonIgnore]
        internal Dictionary<String, Object> properties = new Dictionary<String, Object>();

        [IgnoreProperty]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public override Object this[String propertyName]
        {
            get
            {
                object val;

                if (properties.TryGetValue(propertyName, out val)) {
                    return val;
                }

                var prop = this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
                if (prop != null && prop.CanRead) {
                    return prop.GetValue(this);
                }
                return null;
            }

            set
            {
                isDearty = true;
                var prop = this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
                if (prop != null && prop.CanWrite) {
                    prop.SetValue(this, value);
                } else {
                    properties[propertyName] = value;
                }

                var val = value as String;
                if (value == null || (val != null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(val))) {
                    properties.Remove(propertyName);
                }   
            }
        }

        public DynamicMetaObject GetMetaObject(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression parameter)
        {
            return new DynamicDictionaryPropertyStore<DynamicModelObject>(parameter, this);
        }

        [IgnoreProperty]
        public IEnumerable<String> DynamicPropertyMemberNames
        {
            get
            {
                foreach (var key in properties.Keys) {
                    yield return key;
                }
            }
        }

        private List<String> staticProperties = null;

        [IgnoreProperty]
        private IEnumerable<String> StaticPropertyMemberNames
        {
            get
            {
                if (staticProperties == null) {
                    staticProperties = new List<String>();
                    foreach (var prop in this.GetType()
                        .GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty)) {
                        if (!Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(IgnorePropertyAttribute)) && !Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(ScriptIgnoreAttribute))) {
                            staticProperties.Add(prop.Name);
                            yield return prop.Name;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    foreach (var prop in staticProperties) {
                        yield return prop;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        [IgnoreProperty]
        private IEnumerable<String> AllPropertyMemberNames
        {
            get
            {
                foreach (var prop in DynamicPropertyMemberNames.Concat(StaticPropertyMemberNames)) {
                    yield return prop;
                }
            }
        }

        private class DynamicDictionaryPropertyStore<T> : DynamicMetaObject where T : DynamicModelObject
        {
            private T target;

            internal DynamicDictionaryPropertyStore(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression parameter, T target)
                : base(parameter, BindingRestrictions.Empty, target)
            {
                this.target = target;
            }

            public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
            {
                return target.DynamicPropertyMemberNames;
            }

            public override DynamicMetaObject BindSetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject value)
            {
                BindingRestrictions restrictions = BindingRestrictions.GetTypeRestriction(Expression, LimitType);
                System.Linq.Expressions.Expression self = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert(Expression, LimitType);

                if (binder == null) return null;

                var body = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(self, "Item", System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(binder.Name));
                var convert = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(value.Value), typeof(object));
                var lambda = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Assign(body, convert);

                return new DynamicMetaObject(lambda, restrictions);
            }

            public override DynamicMetaObject BindGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder)
            {
                BindingRestrictions restrictions = BindingRestrictions.GetTypeRestriction(Expression, LimitType);
                System.Linq.Expressions.Expression self = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert(Expression, LimitType);

                if (binder == null) return null;

                var body = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(self, "Item", System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(binder.Name));

                return new DynamicMetaObject(body, restrictions);
            }
        }
    }
```

Whats going on??

Comment: Can you provide your class which implements IDynamicMetaObjectProvider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of `DynamicModelObject` is not correct. In `DynamicDictionaryPropertyStore` child class you do the following:

```
public override DynamicMetaObject BindSetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject value) {
    BindingRestrictions restrictions = BindingRestrictions.GetTypeRestriction(Expression, LimitType);
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression self = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert(Expression, LimitType);

    if (binder == null) return null;
    var body = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(self, "Item", System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(binder.Name));
    var convert = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(value.Value), typeof(object));
    var lambda = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Assign(body, convert);

    return new DynamicMetaObject(lambda, restrictions);
}
```

If you will look at the resulting expression you have, you will see (for example for `PropA`):

```
Convert($arg0).Item["PropA"] = Convert("1")
```

So as a setter you return expression which calls your indexer and assigns constant value (1), regardless of what value was actully passed. This expression will be used later for all setters to `PropA` (cached). Hence your problem: all your setters will ignore passed values and will always assign value with which you called them for a first time. To fix, replace this line:

```
var convert = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(value.Value), typeof(object));
```

With this:

```
var convert = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert(value.Expression, typeof(object));
```

Resulting setter expression will be:

```
Convert($arg0).Item["PropA"] = Convert($arg1)
```

Note that no costants are there, just arguments. After that your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks! It's working now as expected. I would have never searched at this place, but seeing your answer it is fully understandable why this has happened.